# Cant get list view group expander header to display

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to group a list of items in a WPF list view - its working fine but I cant get the expanders header to show.

I set the group style as follows:

```
<!--  Styles the groups  -->
            <ListView.GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate>
                                        <Expander BorderBrush="LightBlue"
                                            BorderThickness="1"
                                            IsExpanded="True"
                                                  Name="groupExpander"
                                            Header="{Binding Family}">

                                            <ItemsPresenter />
                                        </Expander>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                </GroupStyle>
            </ListView.GroupStyle>
```

and the list view items source is bound in the code behind:

```
//group by shape family
CollectionView view = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(GetShapes());
PropertyGroupDescription groupDescription = new PropertyGroupDescription("Family");
view.GroupDescriptions.Add(groupDescription);
ImagesListView.ItemsSource = view;
```

And finally I am binding to a List of this object (I want to group on the family field with this string appearing in the group header:

```
public class Shape
{
        public int ID { get; private set; }
        public byte[] Image { get; private set; }
        public string Description { get; private set; }
        public string Family { get; private set; }
```

}

What am I not doing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change

```
Header="{Binding Family}"
```

to

```
Header="{Binding Name}"
```

Each group is a [`CollectionViewGroup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewgroup(v=vs.110).aspx) where `Name` is the value that you group by

Comment: OMG thank you so much - 2 hours of hitting my head against a cold cup of coffee and it was that simple!